# Prestashop override methods not working in module

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm creating a new module and i want to override some classes and controllers. I created files in my module folder /override and there are copying to override folder on server, but files looks like that:

```
<?php
include_once(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.'namevariations/classes/NameVariation.php');
class OrderHistory extends OrderHistoryCore
{
}
```

When my override file in module folder looks like that:

```
<?php

include_once(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.'namevariations/classes/NameVariation.php');

class OrderHistory extends OrderHistoryCore
{
    public function sendEmail($order, $template_vars = false)
    {
        $result = Db::getInstance()->getRow('
            SELECT osl.`template`, c.`lastname`, c.`firstname`, osl.`name` AS osname, c.`email`, os.`module_name`, os.`id_order_state`, os.`pdf_invoice`, os.`pdf_delivery`
            FROM `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'order_history` oh
                LEFT JOIN `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'orders` o ON oh.`id_order` = o.`id_order`
                LEFT JOIN `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'customer` c ON o.`id_customer` = c.`id_customer`
                LEFT JOIN `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'order_state` os ON oh.`id_order_state` = os.`id_order_state`
                LEFT JOIN `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'order_state_lang` osl ON (os.`id_order_state` = osl.`id_order_state` AND osl.`id_lang` = o.`id_lang`)
            WHERE oh.`id_order_history` = ' . (int) $this->id . ' AND os.`send_email` = 1');
        if (isset($result['template']) && Validate::isEmail($result['email'])) {
            ShopUrl::cacheMainDomainForShop($order->id_shop);

            $topic = $result['osname'];
            $carrierUrl = '';
            if (Validate::isLoadedObject($carrier = new Carrier((int) $order->id_carrier, $order->id_lang))) {
                $carrierUrl = $carrier->url;
            }

            $namevariation = NameVariation::getByName($result['firstname']);

            if($namevariation === false){
                $namevariation['dopelniacz'] = $result['firstname'];
                $namevariation['celownik'] = $result['firstname'];
                $namevariation['biernik'] = $result['firstname'];
                $namevariation['narzednik'] = $result['firstname'];
                $namevariation['miejscownik'] = $result['firstname'];
            }

            $data = array(
                '{lastname}' => $result['lastname'],
                '{firstname}' => $result['firstname'],
                '{id_order}' => (int) $this->id_order,
                '{order_name}' => $order->getUniqReference(),
                '{followup}' => str_replace('@', $order->getWsShippingNumber(), $carrierUrl),
                '{shipping_number}' => $order->getWsShippingNumber(),
                '{dopelniacz}' => $namevariation['dopelniacz'],
                '{celownik}' => $namevariation['celownik'],
                '{biernik}' => $namevariation['biernik'],
                '{narzednik}' => $namevariation['narzednik'],
                '{miejscownik}' => $namevariation['miejscownik'],
            );

            if ($result['module_name']) {
                $module = Module::getInstanceByName($result['module_name']);
                if (Validate::isLoadedObject($module) && isset($module->extra_mail_vars) && is_array($module->extra_mail_vars)) {
                    $data = array_merge($data, $module->extra_mail_vars);
                }
            }

            if (is_array($template_vars)) {
                $data = array_merge($data, $template_vars);
            }

            $data['{total_paid}'] = Tools::displayPrice((float) $order->total_paid, new Currency((int) $order->id_currency), false);

            if (Validate::isLoadedObject($order)) {
                // Attach invoice and / or delivery-slip if they exists and status is set to attach them
                if (($result['pdf_invoice'] || $result['pdf_delivery'])) {
                    $context = Context::getContext();
                    $invoice = $order->getInvoicesCollection();
                    $file_attachement = array();

                    if ($result['pdf_invoice'] && (int) Configuration::get('PS_INVOICE') && $order->invoice_number) {
                        Hook::exec('actionPDFInvoiceRender', array('order_invoice_list' => $invoice));
                        $pdf = new PDF($invoice, PDF::TEMPLATE_INVOICE, $context->smarty);
                        $file_attachement['invoice']['content'] = $pdf->render(false);
                        $file_attachement['invoice']['name'] = Configuration::get('PS_INVOICE_PREFIX', (int) $order->id_lang, null, $order->id_shop) . sprintf('%06d', $order->invoice_number) . '.pdf';
                        $file_attachement['invoice']['mime'] = 'application/pdf';
                    }
                    if ($result['pdf_delivery'] && $order->delivery_number) {
                        $pdf = new PDF($invoice, PDF::TEMPLATE_DELIVERY_SLIP, $context->smarty);
                        $file_attachement['delivery']['content'] = $pdf->render(false);
                        $file_attachement['delivery']['name'] = Configuration::get('PS_DELIVERY_PREFIX', Context::getContext()->language->id, null, $order->id_shop) . sprintf('%06d', $order->delivery_number) . '.pdf';
                        $file_attachement['delivery']['mime'] = 'application/pdf';
                    }
                } else {
                    $file_attachement = null;
                }

                if (!Mail::Send(
                    (int) $order->id_lang,
                    $result['template'],
                    $topic,
                    $data,
                    $result['email'],
                    $result['firstname'] . ' ' . $result['lastname'],
                    null,
                    null,
                    $file_attachement,
                    null,
                    _PS_MAIL_DIR_,
                    false,
                    (int) $order->id_shop
                )) {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            ShopUrl::resetMainDomainCache();
        }

        return true;
    }

    public function changeIdOrderState($new_order_state, $id_order, $use_existing_payment = false)
    {
        if (!$new_order_state || !$id_order) {
            return;
        }

        if (!is_object($id_order) && is_numeric($id_order)) {
            $order = new Order((int) $id_order);
        } elseif (is_object($id_order)) {
            $order = $id_order;
        } else {
            return;
        }

        ShopUrl::cacheMainDomainForShop($order->id_shop);

        $new_os = new OrderState((int) $new_order_state, $order->id_lang);
        $old_os = $order->getCurrentOrderState();

        // executes hook
        if (in_array($new_os->id, array(Configuration::get('PS_OS_PAYMENT'), Configuration::get('PS_OS_WS_PAYMENT')))) {
            Hook::exec('actionPaymentConfirmation', array('id_order' => (int) $order->id), null, false, true, false, $order->id_shop);
        }

        // executes hook
        Hook::exec('actionOrderStatusUpdate', array('newOrderStatus' => $new_os, 'id_order' => (int) $order->id), null, false, true, false, $order->id_shop);

        if (Validate::isLoadedObject($order) && ($new_os instanceof OrderState)) {
            $context = Context::getContext();

            // An email is sent the first time a virtual item is validated
            $virtual_products = $order->getVirtualProducts();
            if ($virtual_products && (!$old_os || !$old_os->logable) && $new_os && $new_os->logable) {
                $assign = array();
                foreach ($virtual_products as $key => $virtual_product) {
                    $id_product_download = ProductDownload::getIdFromIdProduct($virtual_product['product_id']);
                    $product_download = new ProductDownload($id_product_download);
                    // If this virtual item has an associated file, we'll provide the link to download the file in the email
                    if ($product_download->display_filename != '') {
                        $assign[$key]['name'] = $product_download->display_filename;
                        $dl_link = $product_download->getTextLink(false, $virtual_product['download_hash'])
                            . '&id_order=' . (int) $order->id
                            . '&secure_key=' . $order->secure_key;
                        $assign[$key]['link'] = $dl_link;
                        if (isset($virtual_product['download_deadline']) && $virtual_product['download_deadline'] != '0000-00-00 00:00:00') {
                            $assign[$key]['deadline'] = Tools::displayDate($virtual_product['download_deadline']);
                        }
                        if ($product_download->nb_downloadable != 0) {
                            $assign[$key]['downloadable'] = (int) $product_download->nb_downloadable;
                        }
                    }
                }

                $customer = new Customer((int) $order->id_customer);

                $namevariation = NameVariation::getByName($customer->firstname);

                if($namevariation === false){
                    $namevariation['dopelniacz'] = $customer->firstname;
                    $namevariation['celownik'] = $customer->firstname;
                    $namevariation['biernik'] = $customer->firstname;
                    $namevariation['narzednik'] = $customer->firstname;
                    $namevariation['miejscownik'] = $customer->firstname;
                }

                $links = '<ul>';
                foreach ($assign as $product) {
                    $links .= '<li>';
                    $links .= '<a href="' . $product['link'] . '">' . Tools::htmlentitiesUTF8($product['name']) . '</a>';
                    if (isset($product['deadline'])) {
                        $links .= '&nbsp;' . $this->trans('expires on %s.', array($product['deadline']), 'Admin.Orderscustomers.Notification');
                    }
                    if (isset($product['downloadable'])) {
                        $links .= '&nbsp;' . $this->trans('downloadable %d time(s)', array((int) $product['downloadable']), 'Admin.Orderscustomers.Notification');
                    }
                    $links .= '</li>';
                }
                $links .= '</ul>';
                $data = array(
                    '{lastname}' => $customer->lastname,
                    '{firstname}' => $customer->firstname,
                    '{id_order}' => (int) $order->id,
                    '{order_name}' => $order->getUniqReference(),
                    '{nbProducts}' => count($virtual_products),
                    '{virtualProducts}' => $links,
                    '{dopelniacz}' => $namevariation['dopelniacz'],
                    '{celownik}' => $namevariation['celownik'],
                    '{biernik}' => $namevariation['biernik'],
                    '{narzednik}' => $namevariation['narzednik'],
                    '{miejscownik}' => $namevariation['miejscownik'],
                );
                // If there is at least one downloadable file
                if (!empty($assign)) {
                    $orderLanguage = new Language((int) $order->id_lang);
                    Mail::Send(
                        (int) $order->id_lang,
                        'download_product',
                        Context::getContext()->getTranslator()->trans(
                            'The virtual product that you bought is available for download',
                            array(),
                            'Emails.Subject',
                            $orderLanguage->locale
                        ),
                        $data,
                        $customer->email,
                        $customer->firstname . ' ' . $customer->lastname,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        _PS_MAIL_DIR_,
                        false,
                        (int) $order->id_shop
                    );
                }
            }

            /** @since 1.5.0 : gets the stock manager */
            $manager = null;
            if (Configuration::get('PS_ADVANCED_STOCK_MANAGEMENT')) {
                $manager = StockManagerFactory::getManager();
            }

            $error_or_canceled_statuses = array(Configuration::get('PS_OS_ERROR'), Configuration::get('PS_OS_CANCELED'));

            $employee = null;
            if (!(int) $this->id_employee || !Validate::isLoadedObject(($employee = new Employee((int) $this->id_employee)))) {
                if (!Validate::isLoadedObject($old_os) && $context != null) {
                    // First OrderHistory, there is no $old_os, so $employee is null before here
                    $employee = $context->employee; // filled if from BO and order created (because no old_os)
                    if ($employee) {
                        $this->id_employee = $employee->id;
                    }
                } else {
                    $employee = null;
                }
            }

            // foreach products of the order
            foreach ($order->getProductsDetail() as $product) {
                if (Validate::isLoadedObject($old_os)) {
                    // if becoming logable => adds sale
                    if ($new_os->logable && !$old_os->logable) {
                        ProductSale::addProductSale($product['product_id'], $product['product_quantity']);
                        // @since 1.5.0 - Stock Management
                        if (!Pack::isPack($product['product_id']) &&
                            in_array($old_os->id, $error_or_canceled_statuses) &&
                            !StockAvailable::dependsOnStock($product['id_product'], (int) $order->id_shop)) {
                            StockAvailable::updateQuantity($product['product_id'], $product['product_attribute_id'], -(int) $product['product_quantity'], $order->id_shop);
                        }
                    } elseif (!$new_os->logable && $old_os->logable) {
                        // if becoming unlogable => removes sale
                        ProductSale::removeProductSale($product['product_id'], $product['product_quantity']);

                        // @since 1.5.0 - Stock Management
                        if (!Pack::isPack($product['product_id']) &&
                            in_array($new_os->id, $error_or_canceled_statuses) &&
                            !StockAvailable::dependsOnStock($product['id_product'])) {
                            StockAvailable::updateQuantity($product['product_id'], $product['product_attribute_id'], (int) $product['product_quantity'], $order->id_shop);
                        }
                    } elseif (!$new_os->logable && !$old_os->logable &&
                        in_array($new_os->id, $error_or_canceled_statuses) &&
                        !in_array($old_os->id, $error_or_canceled_statuses) &&
                        !StockAvailable::dependsOnStock($product['id_product'])
                    ) {
                        // if waiting for payment => payment error/canceled
                        StockAvailable::updateQuantity($product['product_id'], $product['product_attribute_id'], (int) $product['product_quantity'], $order->id_shop);
                    }
                }
                // From here, there is 2 cases : $old_os exists, and we can test shipped state evolution,
                // Or old_os does not exists, and we should consider that initial shipped state is 0 (to allow decrease of stocks)

                // @since 1.5.0 : if the order is being shipped and this products uses the advanced stock management :
                // decrements the physical stock using $id_warehouse
                if ($new_os->shipped == 1 && (!Validate::isLoadedObject($old_os) || $old_os->shipped == 0) &&
                    Configuration::get('PS_ADVANCED_STOCK_MANAGEMENT') &&
                    Warehouse::exists($product['id_warehouse']) &&
                    $manager != null &&
                    (int) $product['advanced_stock_management'] == 1) {
                    // gets the warehouse
                    $warehouse = new Warehouse($product['id_warehouse']);

                    // decrements the stock (if it's a pack, the StockManager does what is needed)
                    $manager->removeProduct(
                        $product['product_id'],
                        $product['product_attribute_id'],
                        $warehouse,
                        ($product['product_quantity'] - $product['product_quantity_refunded'] - $product['product_quantity_return']),
                        Configuration::get('PS_STOCK_CUSTOMER_ORDER_REASON'),
                        true,
                        (int) $order->id,
                        0,
                        $employee
                    );
                } elseif ($new_os->shipped == 0 && Validate::isLoadedObject($old_os) && $old_os->shipped == 1 &&
                    Configuration::get('PS_ADVANCED_STOCK_MANAGEMENT') &&
                    Warehouse::exists($product['id_warehouse']) &&
                    $manager != null &&
                    (int) $product['advanced_stock_management'] == 1
                ) {
                    // @since.1.5.0 : if the order was shipped, and is not anymore, we need to restock products

                    // if the product is a pack, we restock every products in the pack using the last negative stock mvts
                    if (Pack::isPack($product['product_id'])) {
                        $pack_products = Pack::getItems($product['product_id'], Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT', null, null, $order->id_shop));
                        foreach ($pack_products as $pack_product) {
                            if ($pack_product->advanced_stock_management == 1) {
                                $mvts = StockMvt::getNegativeStockMvts($order->id, $pack_product->id, 0, $pack_product->pack_quantity * $product['product_quantity']);
                                foreach ($mvts as $mvt) {
                                    $manager->addProduct(
                                        $pack_product->id,
                                        0,
                                        new Warehouse($mvt['id_warehouse']),
                                        $mvt['physical_quantity'],
                                        null,
                                        $mvt['price_te'],
                                        true,
                                        null,
                                        $employee
                                    );
                                }
                                if (!StockAvailable::dependsOnStock($product['id_product'])) {
                                    StockAvailable::updateQuantity($pack_product->id, 0, (int) $pack_product->pack_quantity * $product['product_quantity'], $order->id_shop);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        // else, it's not a pack, re-stock using the last negative stock mvts

                        $mvts = StockMvt::getNegativeStockMvts(
                            $order->id,
                            $product['product_id'],
                            $product['product_attribute_id'],
                            ($product['product_quantity'] - $product['product_quantity_refunded'] - $product['product_quantity_return'])
                        );

                        foreach ($mvts as $mvt) {
                            $manager->addProduct(
                                $product['product_id'],
                                $product['product_attribute_id'],
                                new Warehouse($mvt['id_warehouse']),
                                $mvt['physical_quantity'],
                                null,
                                $mvt['price_te'],
                                true
                            );
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Save movement if :
                // not Configuration::get('PS_ADVANCED_STOCK_MANAGEMENT')
                // new_os->shipped != old_os->shipped
                if (Validate::isLoadedObject($old_os) && Validate::isLoadedObject($new_os) && $new_os->shipped != $old_os->shipped && !Configuration::get('PS_ADVANCED_STOCK_MANAGEMENT')) {
                    $product_quantity = (int) ($product['product_quantity'] - $product['product_quantity_refunded'] - $product['product_quantity_return']);

                    if ($product_quantity > 0) {
                        $current_shop_context_type = Context::getContext()->shop->getContextType();
                        if ($current_shop_context_type !== Shop::CONTEXT_SHOP) {
                            //change to order shop context
                            $current_shop_group_id = Context::getContext()->shop->getContextShopGroupID();
                            Context::getContext()->shop->setContext(Shop::CONTEXT_SHOP, $order->id_shop);
                        }
                        (new StockManager())->saveMovement(
                            (int) $product['product_id'],
                            (int) $product['product_attribute_id'],
                            (int) $product_quantity * ($new_os->shipped == 1 ? -1 : 1),
                            array(
                                'id_order' => $order->id,
                                'id_stock_mvt_reason' => ($new_os->shipped == 1 ? Configuration::get('PS_STOCK_CUSTOMER_ORDER_REASON') : Configuration::get('PS_STOCK_CUSTOMER_ORDER_CANCEL_REASON')),
                            )
                        );
                        //back to current shop context
                        if ($current_shop_context_type !== Shop::CONTEXT_SHOP) {
                            Context::getContext()->shop->setContext($current_shop_context_type, $current_shop_group_id);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $this->id_order_state = (int) $new_order_state;

        // changes invoice number of order ?
        if (!Validate::isLoadedObject($new_os) || !Validate::isLoadedObject($order)) {
            die(Tools::displayError($this->trans('Invalid new order status', array(), 'Admin.Orderscustomers.Notification')));
        }

        // the order is valid if and only if the invoice is available and the order is not cancelled
        $order->current_state = $this->id_order_state;
        $order->valid = $new_os->logable;
        $order->update();

        if ($new_os->invoice && !$order->invoice_number) {
            $order->setInvoice($use_existing_payment);
        } elseif ($new_os->delivery && !$order->delivery_number) {
            $order->setDeliverySlip();
        }

        // set orders as paid
        if ($new_os->paid == 1) {
            $invoices = $order->getInvoicesCollection();
            if ($order->total_paid != 0) {
                $payment_method = Module::getInstanceByName($order->module);
            }

            foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
                /** @var OrderInvoice $invoice */
                $rest_paid = $invoice->getRestPaid();
                if ($rest_paid > 0) {
                    $payment = new OrderPayment();
                    $payment->order_reference = Tools::substr($order->reference, 0, 9);
                    $payment->id_currency = $order->id_currency;
                    $payment->amount = $rest_paid;

                    if ($order->total_paid != 0) {
                        $payment->payment_method = $payment_method->displayName;
                    } else {
                        $payment->payment_method = null;
                    }

                    // Update total_paid_real value for backward compatibility reasons
                    if ($payment->id_currency == $order->id_currency) {
                        $order->total_paid_real += $payment->amount;
                    } else {
                        $order->total_paid_real += Tools::ps_round(Tools::convertPrice($payment->amount, $payment->id_currency, false), 2);
                    }
                    $order->save();

                    $payment->conversion_rate = ($order ? $order->conversion_rate : 1);
                    $payment->save();
                    Db::getInstance()->execute('
                    INSERT INTO `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'order_invoice_payment` (`id_order_invoice`, `id_order_payment`, `id_order`)
                    VALUES(' . (int) $invoice->id . ', ' . (int) $payment->id . ', ' . (int) $order->id . ')');
                }
            }
        }

        // updates delivery date even if it was already set by another state change
        if ($new_os->delivery) {
            $order->setDelivery();
        }

        // executes hook
        Hook::exec('actionOrderStatusPostUpdate', array('newOrderStatus' => $new_os, 'id_order' => (int) $order->id), null, false, true, false, $order->id_shop);

        // sync all stock
        (new StockManagerAdapter())->updatePhysicalProductQuantity(
            (int) $order->id_shop,
            (int) Configuration::get('PS_OS_ERROR'),
            (int) Configuration::get('PS_OS_CANCELED'),
            null,
            (int) $order->id
        );

        ShopUrl::resetMainDomainCache();
    }
}
```

Why method is not copying to file? It's something wrong there?

Comment: Post your folders structure plz

Comment: Overrided class is in ```modulefolder/override/classes/order/OrderHistory.php``` thisi is correct, files are creating but without functions

Comment: So do the installation again while the debug mode is enabled

Comment: This class is already override by another module ?